# Show that current post is number X out of X

Tags: posts, count

Is it possible to echo at the end of a post which number the current post is?

For example;

Say you're viewing the 4th most recent post out of a total of 10, somewhere at the foot of the post I need it to say **"Post 4/10"**...

Is that possible?

Comment: What you would like "total" to be of? All published posts? How do you want to calculate order - does 4th post becomes 5th if new one is published?

Comment: Only published posts and yes, when a new post is published post 4 would become 5, 5 would become 6, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with `$query->current_post` and `$query->post_count` with `$query = new WP_Query(args);`. With this you may get the position and the total of posts.

Comment: Doesn't have to be new query, actually doing this with _main_ query would be more fitting answer _hint-hint_. :)

Comment: right ! but it can be a second loop.